# Is this possible to deny logout with bash shell .bash_logout?

Tags: bash

I wish to use this `.bash_logout` script to check some things before the user log out and possibly deny to log out if things to do remains.

My use case is to check if a `git` repo is clean before allowing the user to log out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> ```
>    When  a  login  shell  exits, bash reads and executes commands from the
>    file ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.
> ```

The current login shell is on its way out when `~/.bash_logout` runs.
But it doesn't prevent you from starting another login shell,
which will give the illusion that logout was prevented:

```
exec bash -l
```